# IMFMediaSource "no symbol loaded for mfcore.dll" and QueryInterface gives "E_NOINTERFACE"

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, ms-media-foundation

I'am new to COM programming but well versed in C#.Net, trying to run this code but for some reason IMFMediaSource object doesn't get initialized as the Visual studio in debug mode when i check the value by hovering over "pSource" pointer it shows "Information Not available, no symbol loaded for mfcore.dll" however the hr returns "S_Ok" but when the Next Statement executes "QueryInterface" the hr returns "E_NOINTERFACE".

Kindly please explain in detail what i'm doing wrong as my main motive is to make a DLL for video capture and Use it with Unity Engine C#.

```
#pragma comment(lib,"mfplat.lib")
#pragma message("linking with Microsoft's Media Foundation mfplat library ...")
#pragma comment(lib,"mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"mfcore.lib")
#pragma message("linking with Microsoft's Media Foundation mf library ...")
#pragma comment(lib,"mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma message("linking with Microsoft's Media Foundation mfreadwrite library ...")
#pragma comment(lib,"mfuuid.lib")
#pragma message("linking with Microsoft's Media Foundation mfuuid library ...")
#pragma comment(lib,"d3d9.lib")
#pragma message("linking with Microsoft's DirectX 3D 9 library ...")
#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")
#pragma message("linking with Microsoft's shlwapi library ...")
#pragma comment(lib,"Advapi32.lib")
#pragma message("linking with Microsoft's Advapi32 library ...")

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        abort();
    hr = ::MFStartup(MF_VERSION, MFSTARTUP_NOSOCKET);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        abort();
    IMFMediaSource*  media_source = 0;
    IMFSourceReader* source_reader = 0;
    IMFAttributes* pAttributes = 0;
    hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 1);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        abort();
    // Set the device type to video.
    hr = pAttributes->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE, MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        abort();
    UINT32 count;
    IMFActivate **ppDevices = NULL;
    hr = MFEnumDeviceSources(pAttributes, &ppDevices, &count);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        abort();
    if (count == 0)
        abort();
    // Create the media source object.
    IMFMediaSource *pSource = NULL;
    hr = ppDevices[0]->ActivateObject(IID_IMFMediaSource, (void**)&pSource);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        abort();
    pSource->AddRef();//on hovering over the "pSource" in VS2017 shows "Information Not available, no symbol loaded for mfcore.dll"    

IMFAttributes* pSourceAttributes = NULL;
    hr = pSource->QueryInterface(IID_IMFAttributes, (void**)&pSourceAttributes);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        abort(); //hr is assigned -> "E_NOINTERFACE" and program quits

    const size_t nDeviceNameSize = 1024;
    LPWSTR pDeviceName = new WCHAR[nDeviceNameSize];
    UINT32 nActualBufferSize;
    hr = pSourceAttributes->GetString(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_SYMBOLIC_LINK, pDeviceName, nDeviceNameSize, &nActualBufferSize);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        abort();
    // Set the symbolic link.
    hr = pAttributes->SetString(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_SYMBOLIC_LINK, pDeviceName);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        abort();
    // Create device source interface
    hr = MFCreateDeviceSource(pAttributes, &media_source);
    if (FAILED(hr)) 
        abort();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IMFAttributes` interface is available on the activation object and not [necessarily] on media source. If you update your code as I show below, you would be able to query `MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_SYMBOLIC_LINK` value. The reason for this is that primitive like media source does not need to keep, expose or even be aware of registration information - media source itself is pure implementation.

```
IMFAttributes* pSourceAttributes = NULL;
hr = //pSource
    ppDevices[0] // <<--------
    ->QueryInterface(IID_IMFAttributes, (void**)&pSourceAttributes);
if (FAILED(hr))
    abort(); //hr is assigned -> "E_NOINTERFACE" and program quits
```

Note that this documented behavior, you can find more details here: [Audio/Video Capture in Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/audio-video-capture-in-media-foundation):

> You can query the activation objects for various attributes, including the following: […]
>   The following example takes an array of `IMFActivate` pointers and prints the display name of each device to the debug window: […]

Comment: thanks it worked, I have another doubts how do i use  "Microsoft Direct3D or Direct2D to preview/display the video" from the media Source and also use sink writer/sink reader to create video file. Kindly please add some code snippets and expain the process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is where samples are helpful, for example, `SimpleCapture`: [on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/SimpleCapture) and [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dd757925.aspx).

Comment: i downloaded the project and opened it with VS2017 it prompted for migration i did it now it shows "Warning treated as Error - no 'object' file generated" in Preview.cpp at line 120.

Comment: where there is a warning regarding the 'DWORD' to 'int' conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Code

> hr = pSource->QueryInterface(IID_IMFAttributes,
>   (void**)&pSourceAttributes);

returns `E_NOINTERFACE` because `MediaSource` is not inherited from `IMFAttributes`. 
For your purpose - get friendly name and symbolic link of the device, code must get `IMFAttributes` from `IMFActivate` (`ppDevices[0]`):

```
// Read friendlyName of device
ResultCode::Result MediaFoundation::readFriendlyName(IMFActivate *pDevice, std::wstring &friendlyName)
{
ResultCode::Result result = ResultCode::MEDIA_FOUNDATION_READFRIENDLYNAME_ERROR;

wchar_t *pFriendlyName = NULL;

HRESULT hr = S_OK;

hr = pDevice->GetAllocatedString(
    MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_FRIENDLY_NAME,
    &pFriendlyName,
    NULL
    );

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    DebugPrintOut::getInstance().printOut(L"MEDIA FOUNDATION: readFriendlyName cannot be executed!!!\n");

    goto finish;
}

friendlyName = std::wstring(pFriendlyName);

result = ResultCode::OK;

 finish:

if (pFriendlyName)
    CoTaskMemFree(pFriendlyName);

return result;
}
```

and:

```
// Read symbolicLink of device
ResultCode::Result MediaFoundation::readSymbolicLink(IMFActivate *pDevice, 
std::wstring &symbolicLink)
{
ResultCode::Result result = ResultCode::MEDIA_FOUNDATION_READSYMBOLICLINK_ERROR;

wchar_t *pSymbolicLink = NULL;

HRESULT hr = S_OK;

hr = pDevice->GetAllocatedString(
        MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_SYMBOLIC_LINK,
        &pSymbolicLink,
        NULL
        );


if (FAILED(hr))
{
    DebugPrintOut::getInstance().printOut(L"MEDIA FOUNDATION: readSymbolicLink cannot be executed!!!\n");

    goto finish;
}

symbolicLink = std::wstring(pSymbolicLink);

result = ResultCode::OK;

finish:

if (pSymbolicLink)
    CoTaskMemFree(pSymbolicLink);

return result;
}
```

I recommend read my article with code: [Capturing Live-video from Web-camera on Windows 7 and Windows 8](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776058/Capturing-Live-video-from-Web-camera-on-Windows-an)

P.S. for Unity Engine I can recommend my another project: [UnityWebCamViewer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK#fourtythirddemoprogram)

Comment: @Evgeny.P Thanks for sharing your projects Sir i highly appreciate it, but i want to create a small very specific small project like capture from multiple devices and write to single or multiple file to understand/learn the MediaFoundation process so that i can build on that skill for an advanced application. can you help me or guide where can i find good resource for learning Media Foundation as MSDN guide is not helping much.

Comment: @Murtaza Sajawala So, Media Foundation is power 
technology, but it is more targeted on WindowsStore platform and Microsoft had stopped publish demo samples for Desktop Windows OS since Windows 7. I can recommend read a book [developing_microsoft_media_foundation_applications.pdf
](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9pVRwN4TMxNeW15TDVJXzB4MEE/view?usp=sharing). If you would like to learn Media Foundation by writing of code - then you must spend much time - in my view minimum 3 months.

Comment: Evgeny Pereguda Sir Thanks for sharing the book and tips.